# How do I use a regular expression to match an eight-digit number that can also have a space in the middle?

Tags: java, regex

I want to match `1234 5678` or `12345678`

Is this regular expression wrong?

```
if(!number.matches("^\\d{4}[, ]\\d{4}$")){
  throw new Exception(" number is not valid : "+number);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try a quantifier after the `[]`

```
^\d{4}[\s,]?\d{4}$
```

Comment: Perhaps a small explanation may help de-mistify this code. This answer states that the string should match a pattern where the first 4 characters are numbers, optionally followed by a whitespace character and a comma, then again followed by a sequence of 4 characters which should all be numbers and must be at the end of the input string.

Was this not your intention?

Answer (score 1):

You are close, you need to specify that the space/comma is optional with a quantifier. `?` is a good one because it means "zero or one". So your expression would be

```
^\d{4}[, ]?\d{4}$
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to match the comma as well? `[, ]` matches a comma or a space char. The effect you're going for looks like `( |)`, except there are better ways to do it:

I think what you're looking for is:

```
/^\d{4}\s?\d{4}$/
```

Note that the \s can match any space char, including newlines. If you **only** want to match the space char `' '`, then use the following:

```
/^\d{4}[ ]?\d{4}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

there is modifcation required to match '12345678'

use this regular expression : **"^\d{4}[, ]?\d{4}$"**

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
 ^\d{4}[\s]?\d{4}$
```

Try this without the comma.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a good time to bring up the [online Regex interactive tutorial](http://www.perlfect.com/articles/regextutor.shtml).
Great tool for playing around with Regex expressions without having to mess up your own code.